# position of my image when i change my mobile view

Tags: javascript, image, css, mobile, position

I got a tiny problem with my image position, so here is the problem, I have my portrait view I swipe my image and when I switch my view (portrait to landscape) my image is not any more centred. my problem is that the margin of my image is still the same as the portrait view and I don't know how to change that.

I already tried to change my margin of my images but nothing to do, it's still take the first view margin that I used.

so here is the `Js/Jq` :

```
function puceTransition(front) {
    var wrapImg = $('.wrapImage');
    var margeLeft = 0;

if(front) {
    if (stateImg == "back") {
        stateImg = "front";

        margeLeft = $('#myImageBack').css("marginLeft").replace("px", "");

        $('#frontImg').addClass('select');
        $('#backImg').removeClass('select');

        $('#myImageBack').animate({opacity: "0.5", marginLeft: ((imgFront + widthImg1 + myButtonRight)) + "px"}, "normal");
        $('#myImageFront').animate({opacity: "1.0", marginLeft: parseInt(margeLeft) + "px"}, "normal");

        $('.imgTitleBack').hide();
        $('.imgTitleFront').show();

        $('#imgButtonLeft').animate({opacity: "0.5"});
        $('#imgButtonRight').animate({opacity: "1.0"});
    }
} else {
    if (stateImg == "front") {
        stateImg = "back";

        margeLeft = $('#myImageFront').css("marginLeft").replace("px", "");

        $('#backImg').addClass('select');
        $('#frontImg').removeClass('select');

        $('#myImageFront').animate({opacity: "0.5", marginLeft: (((-imgFront) + (-widthImg1) + myButtonLeft)) + "px"}, "normal");
        $('#myImageBack').animate({opacity: "1.0", marginLeft: parseInt(margeLeft) + "px"}, "normal");

        $('.imgTitleBack').show();
        $('.imgTitleFront').hide();

        $('#imgButtonLeft').animate({opacity: "1.0"});
        $('#imgButtonRight').animate({opacity: "0.5"});
    }
}
}
```

And here is the css :

```
    .myImage { display: block; position: relative; width: 450px; margin: 0 auto; }
    .myImage.second { margin: -240px 0 0 670px; }
    .myImageAirport { display: block; position: relative; width: 450px; margin: 0 auto; }
    .myImageAirport.second { margin : -220px 0 0 670px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

just add this css to your image class

```
.myImage {
display: block;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}
```

It should work!

Comment: hum i already do that with my margin: 0 auto;
but i tried your code and still the same thing happening :s